# How to solve this problem "Column ambiguously defined"

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Is there any syntax error ? I need to join these columns and insert it to table.
Help me

```
SELECT DISTINCT dept_in_pk.nextval,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.TADIG,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.COUNTRY,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.OPERATOR,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.GSM,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.GPRS,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.CAMEL,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.LTE,
               TEST1.MOC_LOCAL_RECORDS
            FROM REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT, TEST1
            INNER JOIN REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT
            ON TEST1.TADIG = REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.TADIG;
```

Comment: What is this table "dept_in_pk" it's referred in select statement but not in from?

Comment: It's sequence which is increases ID by 1. Auto Increment

Comment: You are mixing outdated implicit joins and the explit `JOIN` operators

Comment: What do you think the impact of DISTINCT would be on a projection which includes a sequence? Spoiler alert: `ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here`

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Comma means cross join with lower precedence than keyword JOINs. So the JOIN is done first & an alias for the table on the left of the comma is not known there. So don't mix comma with keyword joins, it's confusing. PS Your question is a faq easily found by googling your error/title. Please research beforer you consider posting a question. [ask] Also see [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

you have written two times REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT in your query. Please, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dept_in_pk.nextval,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.TADIG,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.COUNTRY,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.OPERATOR,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.GSM,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.GPRS,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.CAMEL,
               REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.LTE,
               TEST1.MOC_LOCAL_RECORDS
          FROM TEST1
         INNER JOIN REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT
            ON TEST1.TADIG = REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.TADIG;
```

Comment: You have fallen into the same trap as the OP: you have not tried running a query which includes both DISTINCT  and a sequence `nextval()` call. it hurls `ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here`

Comment: Oopsie, you're right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't include `REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT` in `FROM` clause! try something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT dept_in_pk.nextval,
    REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.TADIG,
    REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.COUNTRY,
    REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.OPERATOR,
    REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.GSM,
    REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.GPRS,
    REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.CAMEL,
    REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.LTE,
    TEST1.MOC_LOCAL_RECORDS
FROM TEST1
    INNER JOIN REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT ON TEST1.TADIG = REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT.TADIG;
```

Including `REFERENCE_RP_CURRENT` in `FROM` clause duplicates references in that table when you use it (again) in `JOIN` clause.